# C++ factories, and handling subclass arguments

Tags: c++, oop

I have a hierarchy of classes that I'd like to have a factory for creating instances of based on a string type:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() = default;
    virtual ~Base();
}

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1( int param );
}

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2( int param1, int param2 );
}

class MyFactory
{
public:
    virtual Base * CreateInstance() = 0;
};
```

The thing that's annoying me is that CreateInstance() can't be passed arguments because Base has the default ctor. If I insist on providing a default ctor on Derived1 and Derived2 then I may have violated the OO design principle that a ctor leaves an instance in a useable state. Is there a better design?

Comment: Wouldn't your factory class have `CreateDerived1()` and `CreateDerived2()` methods that take the approriate arguments?

Comment: No cause op is using a string to differentiate, but I cant see it anywhere either. The good design here is to make `CreateInstance()` signature relevant to every subclass. Either each subclass constructor have the same arguments  or the factory code should be able to provide the missing ones or ignore the irrelevant ones for each subclass.

Comment: You could make `CreateInstance` a variadic function template, but then it couldn't be `virtual`.

Comment: Could be a maintenance bottleneck?

Comment: @Jean-BernardJansen the string is intended to be elsewhere in a registered map 

typedef Base * (*CtorFunc)();
map<string,CtorFunc> s_ctorMap;

Comment: From a design perspective, it rarely makes sense for a set of derived classes to have different methods of construction.  Even less so if you want to have a factory that knows how to construct each of them without having to modify the factory every time you derive another class from the base.

Comment: The point of the factory is that the user doesn't even know `Derived1` and `Derived2` exist. The factory decides which one to create, the user has no idea. Thus you must provide a uniform creation interface for both derived types. If you can't, you don't have a factory.